# Finding indices of start of repeated adjacent values in a list containing NaN (python)

Tags: python, list

I would like to find indices of beginning of each repeated adjacent values in a list without a for loop.

Given the input: `[NaN, NaN, 1, 2, NaN, 2, 2, 2, 4]`

I want the following output: `[0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8]`

Below is my attempt using a for loop, which gives the correct output:

```html
start_adj_i = []
prev_val = -999 # an impossible value
for i, x in enumerate(input):
    if numpy.isnan(x) and numpy.isnan(prev_val):
        continue
    elif x != prev_val:
        start_adj_i.append(i)
    prev_val = x # update for next iteration
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example clarifies that you're looking for the indices of the elements that start a "run" of identical values, with NaN values being regarded as the same as each other.

In other words – all indices except those elements that are the same as the value before them. For instance, the first element in the array will always be included.

We can construct a mask of those values, then pull out the indices of the entries that are set using `np.where`:

```py
# Convert x to an ndarray for convenience
x = np.array(x)

# Start off with a mask with everything set
mask = np.full(len(x), True)

# Clear the elements where adjacent elements match (note the offset of 1 ...)
mask[1:][x[1:] == x[:-1]] = False

# ... similarly, clear the elements where two adjacent elements are NaN ...
mask[1:][np.isnan(x[:-1]) & np.isnan(x[1:])] = False

# ... and find the indices.
indices = np.where(mask)[0]
```

Of course, this is numpy so we should probably cut that down a bit to make it more likely that whoever reads the code next takes notice of it:

```py
indices, = np.where(np.r_[1,
  np.not_equal(x[1:], x[:-1]) & ~(np.isnan(x[:-1]) & np.isnan(x[1:]))
])
```

Beautiful. That will take them ages to read.